# PHP Variables: Include a file?

Tags: php, variables, include

I found the answer to this question over the internet - but I didn't really get it.

Can someone please give me the answer (the code), and explain it? Cheers!

What I want to know how to do is:

```
<?php

   $variable = include('websitetitle.txt');

<?
```

Cheers.

Comment: can you please give the answer you found already and explain which part of it you dont understand. Your question right now is pretty vague and ambiguous.

Comment: *(reference)* http://php.net/include

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`$variable = file_get_contents('websitetitle.txt');`

Keep in mind this is bad practice, in general (storing data in .txt files).

Comment: Why is that? What if I made it a .php or .html file?

Comment: I think what @Adam_Mac is saying is that you should store data in a database

Comment: Wouldn't matter. When you start storing information row-wise (username, mail etc) with separators - then you'll run into problems. Look up XML or MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean get the content of the txt file, then you should use:

```
 $variable = file_get_contents('websitetitle.txt');
```

Answer (score 0):

`include` evaluates the file as a PHP script, so it needs to contain PHP code to work as in your example. If you want to use a file to hold the name, you should use:

```
$variable = file_get_contents('websitetitle.txt');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can find most stuff in the PHP manual if you append a search term to the `http://php.net/` URL, e.g.: http://php.net/include

In this case, we can read the following:

> It is possible to execute a return() statement inside an included file
>   in order to terminate processing in that file and return to the script
>   which called it. Also, it's possible to return values from included
>   files. You can take the value of the include call as you would for a
>   normal function.

[Some examples follow](http://es.php.net/manual/en/function.include.php#example-129).

Answer (score 0):

It's an oxymoron to provide an explanation of what you *want* to do as code - there are 2 obvious things this might mean:

1. You want to read a file into a variable - in which case you should use file_get_contents()
2. You want to return a value from the include file - in which case either use a return statement within the include file (not recommended) or include the file than call a function defined within it.

Or do you mean something else?